# How can i check if a string is a substring of another and the other caracters of the second are underscore+number?

Tags: php, regex, substring

I have two variable of strings.
E.g.

```
$title = 'string';
$title2 = 'string_01';
```

`$title2` could be the same as `$title` or could be `$title.'_'.number`.

At the moment I do:

```
$sametitle = strpos($title2, $title);
if(!($sametitle === 0)) {
```

If `$title != $title2` I need to check if `$title` is a substring of `$title2`  AND if `$title` is at the beginning of `$title2` AND the rest of the `$title2` string match the underscore+number so that in the case:

```
$title = 'st';
```

it doesn't go into the if.

I think I can do it with preg_match but I don't understand very well regular expressions so I'm not sure how to do it.

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this preg_match:

```
preg_match('/^' . preg_quote($title, '/') . '(_\d+)?$/', $title2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
if (preg_match('~\Q' . $title . '\E_[0-9]+~', $title2, $match)) {
    print_r($match);
}
```

where `\Q.....\E` allows special characters inside `$title`.